# VCL App in C++ Builder and FormCreate Event Better Understanding

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

As someone new to VCL apps, my baseline understanding is that any code included in the `FormCreate` function will be executed when `Form1` is generated and displayed.

So, for example, I call a function that loads two combo boxes, and then another function to display some line and rectangles:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    LoadCombos();
    DrawShapes();
}
```

When the code is run, I only get the loaded combo boxes.

I've walked the code in debug mode and it is executing the `DrawShapes()` function. Below is a snippet of the drawing code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DrawShapes(void)
{
   int x,x1,y1,x2,y2;

   // draw main outline boxes in two rows
   x1=50;
   y1=140;
   x2=275;
   y2=380;
   for (x=0; x<4; x++) {
        Canvas->MoveTo(x1+(x*275),y1);
        Canvas->Rectangle(x1+(x*275),y1,x2+(x*275),y2);
   }
   x1=50;
   y1=440;
   x2=275;
   y2=680;
   for (x=0; x<4; x++) {
       Canvas->MoveTo(x1+(x*275),y1);
       Canvas->Rectangle(x1+(x*275),y1,x2+(x*275),y2);
   }
}
```

I'm definitely not understanding why the drawing code is not showing up. I am assuming the VCL code is send the invalidate and update event messages along the way. I've even tried calling them manually at the beginning and end of the `FormCreate()` function without success.

Any help in understanding why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As someone new to VCL apps, my baseline understanding is that any code included in the `FormCreate` function will be executed when `Form1` is generated and displayed.

The `OnCreate` event is fired while the Form object is being constructed.  This happens *before* the Form's UI window is shown onscreen.

> When the code is run, I only get the loaded combo boxes.

That is because you are drawing on the Form's `Canvas` from outside of the Form's normal drawing sequence.  Every time the Form's window needs to be (re-)drawn onscreen, any previous drawing is erased.  So, do not call your `DrawShapes()` function in the Form's `OnCreate` event, call it in the Form's `OnPaint` event instead.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's probably more what OP wanted :-)

Comment: @Remy Thanks that worked great. Is it better to use the Form canvas or something TImage or TBitmap as there will be more drawing after the startup process?

Comment: @Skypilot65 it really depends on your needs. In the OnPaint event, you have to redraw everything on the Canvas from scratch each time. Might make sense to do if your shapes are changing over time. Or, you could cache reusable drawings with TBitmap and copy them into the Canvas when needed. But if your drawing doesn't change over time, using TImage may make more sense, since it holds its own TBitmap and handles its own painting.